# $_POST method fetches from array and displays result

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

So I want the form to find what the user searches for and then return results for that, through the array down below. Is this possible? I've tried to write the php myself, but I'm clueless.

```
            <form action="result.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="country" size="30" id="autocomplete-ajax" placeholder="Search for country, timezone or city and hit enter!" maxlength="30">
            </form>

                <?php
                $countries = array(   
                "AD" => "Andorra",   
                "AE" => "United Arab Emirates",   
                "AF" => "Afghanistan",
                "AG" => "Antiqua and Barbuda",
                "AI" => "Anguilla",
                "AL" => "Albania",          
                "ZZ" => "Unkown or Invalid Region");

                if (isset($_POST[$countries[0]])){
                echo "<p>Correct!</p>";
                }
                if (isset($_POST[$countries[1]])){
                echo "<p>Correct2</p>";
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: [**Time to do a little research so you can learn what you need in order to achieve what you want :)**](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=php+autocomplete+textbox)

Comment: I have the autocomplete js too it, I just want the input to match what the users searches for with my php array.

Answer (score 0):

```
You could replace the other issets with this - it will check the post values against the array 

   if (isset($_POST["country"])){
        foreach($countries as $k => $c){
            if(strtolower($c) == strtolower(trim($_POST["country"]))){
                 echo "<p>Correct!</p>";
            }
        }
    }
```